# Algorithm for getting current week number after changing the starting day of the week in python?

Tags: python, datetime

I want to design an algorithm which will calculate the week number according to the start week day set. for eg : - If I set the start day as `WEDNESDAY` and currently its 40 week and its `TUESDAY`, it should print 40 as the week number. If it is WEDNESDAY or THURSDAY, I should get 41.

Think of it like a cycle. From Wednesday till tuesday, it should be assigned a week no + 1, then when next wednesday comes, week should be incremented again.

I tried using `calendar.setfirstweekday(calendar.WEDNESDAY)` and then altering my system machine time, all I get is 40 as the week number everytime.

How do I design such as algorithm in python?

I have a similar problem for month, but I have designed a solution for it. Here is it.

```
current_date = datetime.datetime.now()
if current_date.day < gv.month_start_date:
    month   = current_date.month -1
    if month == 0:
        month = 12
    else:
        month = current_date.month
```

How can I design it for week?

Comment: You already have the algorithm right? `if day >= wednesday: week_num += 1` translated to Python.

Comment: What if day is not greater than wednesday? Think of it like a cycle. From Wednesday till tuesday, it should be assigned a week no + 1, then when next wednesday comes, week should be incremented again.

Comment: That's exactly what `if day >= wednesday: week_num += 1` says. According to your explanation, say currently is week 40 and it's Tuesday. The output is 40, so it's correct. If it's wednesday, the output is 41. Again the `if` will produce the output correctly. The next monday, the week_num is already 41, we don't need to add anything. So its output will be 41. I assume that `week_num` here is retrieved from default python library.

Comment: Ohh yeahh.. Let me try it. Thanks.

Comment: how about when it's WED and you move the starting day to THU: `week_num -= 1` then? and then how about if the year started on MON, and now it's THU, so there's one extra week, so the week number stays the same?

Comment: @ErikAllik Good Point. I'm really confused with this. I'm trying to find a generic solution for this as I designed it for month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally designed a solution for this.

```
if current_day >= set_week_day:
    week = current_week
else:
    week = current_week - 1
```

Works for all cases.

Comment: Consider also `week = current_week - 1 if current_day >= set_week_day else current_week` or even `week = current_week - (current_day >= set_week_day)`.

Answer (score 0):

[datetime in python](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isocalendar) has a function called isocalender to get the ISO week number (starts on Monday)

```
import datetime
datetime.date(2013, 9, 30).isocalendar()[1]
```

You can use this with a little bit of logic (this script should have the week begin on Wednesdays)

```
import datetime

day = 30
month = 9
year = 2013
weekcount = datetime.date(year, month, day).isocalendar()[1]
if datetime.date(year, month, day).isocalendar()[2] <= 3: # start on wednesday
    weekcount -= 1
print weekcount
```